# jQuery - Select parent li from Div contents

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select a parent LI depending on what is inside of a div, here is where I am currently...

http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/1257/

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <div>
        Myitem
    </div>
    <div>
        John Resig
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>

$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

This correctly underlines the div containing the word John, I now want it to apply some styling to the parent li that contains this div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .parents() or .parent()

```
$( "div:contains('John')" ).parents("li:first").css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

another way: use ":has"

```
$( "li:has(div:contains('John'))" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `closest` to travel up and find the nearest ancestor that matches the selector:

```
$( "div:contains('John')" ).closest('li').css("text-decoration", "underline")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" ).parent().css("background-color", "green");
```

Should do the trick